# How to change kivyMD presplash to custom screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I am working on a application where pre splash is coaded using main.py and design.kv. When i convert this code to apk using collab buildozer the app crashes i think there is problem due to pre splash any solution how i can display custom pre-splash

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
import requests
Window.size = (350, 580)
class PreSplash(Screen):
    pass
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass
class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass
class RoundedGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("design.kv")
        return kv

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.login, 2)

    def login(self, *args):
        self.root.current = "login_screen"

    def on_submit(self, username, password):
        if username == "Admin" and password == "Pass":
            self.root.current = "second_screen"

    def button_click(self, Text):
        url = "http://IP Address/post"
        data = {"BtnText": Text}
        response = requests.post(url, data=data)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Data sent is: " + Text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

design.kv

```
ScreenManagement:
    PreSplash:
    LoginScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<PreSplash>:
    name: "pre-splash"

    MDScreen:
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: 226/255, 0, 48/255, 1

            Image:
                source: "Assets/logo.jpg"
                size_hint: .33, .33
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .55}
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 1, 1, 1, 1
                    Ellipse:
                        size: 130, 130
                        pos: 110, 250

            MDLabel:
                text: "Imech Industry"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
                halign: "center"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                font_size: "30sp"
                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"

            MDLabel:
                text: "Gearing to Brighter Future"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
                halign: "center"
                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                font_size: "13sp"
                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Regular.ttf"

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login_screen"

    MDScreen:
        name: "login"
        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

            MDIconButton:
                icon: "chevron-left"
                user_font_size: "35sp"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .945}

            MDLabel:
                text: "Back"
                font_size: "18sp"
                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .615, "center_y": .945}

            Image:
                source: "logo.jpg"
                size_hint: .37, .37
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .29, "center_y": .8}

            MDLabel:
                text: "Proceed with your"
                font_size: "22sp"
                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
                color: 120/255, 120/255, 120/255, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .65}

            MDLabel:
                text: "Login"
                font_size: "28sp"
                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .58}

            MDFloatLayout:
                size_hint: .79, .08
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .42}

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Username"
                    font_size: "14sp"
                    font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}

                TextInput:
                    id: username_field
                    size_hint_y: .75
                    font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .49, "center_y": .4}
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    cursor_width: "2sp"
                    foreground_color: 120/255, 120/255, 120/255, 1
                    font_size: "17sp"
                    multiline: False

                Image:
                    source: "user.png"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .94, "center_y": .5}
                    size_hint: .5, .5

                MDFloatLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
                    size_hint_y: .03
                    md_bg_color: 120/255, 120/255, 120/255, 1

            MDFloatLayout:
                size_hint: .79, .08
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .28}

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Password"
                    font_size: "14sp"
                    font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}

                TextInput:
                    id: password_field
                    size_hint_y: .75
                    font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .49, "center_y": .4}
                    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                    cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                    cursor_width: "2sp"
                    font_size: "17sp"
                    multiline: False
                    password: True

                Image:
                    source: "key.png"
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .94, "center_y": .5}
                    size_hint: .3, .3

                MDFloatLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0}
                    size_hint_y: .03
                    md_bg_color: 120/255, 120/255, 120/255, 1

            Button:
                text: "Login"
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
                size_hint: .79, .08
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
                on_release:
                    app.on_submit(username_field.text, password_field.text)

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: 226/225, 0, 48/225, 1

                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                        radius: [2]

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "second_screen"
    MDScreen:
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            md_bg_color: .93, .93, .93,1
            MDTopAppBar:
                elevation:1
                title:"I Mech Industries"
                md_bg_color: .13, .16, .19,1
                opposite_colors: True

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint_x: .95
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                MDGridLayout:
                    rows: 2
                    padding: {10, 5, 10 ,5}
                    size_hint: 1, 1
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Row 1 Label"
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: "30dp"
                        font_size: "14sp"
                        font_name: "Assets/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"
                    RoundedGridLayout:
                        cols: 2
                        padding: "10dp"

                        canvas.before:
                            Color:
                                rgba: .80,.80,.80,1
                            RoundedRectangle:
                                pos: self.pos
                                size: self.size
                                radius: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                        MDAnchorLayout:
                            size_hint_x:0.4
                            orientation : 'vertical'
                            md_bg_color: .80,.80,.80,1
                            spacing : 10
                            padding : 5
                            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                                text: "Button 1"
                                icon: "android"
                                on_release: app.button_click(self.text)
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
                                line_width: 1.25
                                font_size: "15sp"
                                size_hint: None, None
                                size: "200dp", "200dp"
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: 0, .68, .71, 1
                                line_color: 0, .68, .71, 1
                                icon_color: 0, .68, .71, 1

                        MDAnchorLayout:
                            size_hint_x:0.4
                            orientation : 'vertical'
                            md_bg_color: .80,.80,.80,1
                            spacing : 10
                            padding : 5
                            MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
                                text: "Button 2"
                                icon: "android"
                                on_release: app.button_click(self.text)
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                                font_name: "Assets/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
                                line_width: 1.25
                                font_size: "15sp"
                                size_hint: None, None
                                size: "200dp", "200dp"
                                theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                text_color: 0, .68, .71, 1
                                line_color: 0, .68, .71, 1
                                icon_color: 0, .68, .71, 1
```

Here is the buildozer spec file

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3, kivy==2.1.0, kivymd==1.1.1, sdl2_ttf==2.0.15, pillow

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 2.2.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
#android.permissions = android.permission.INTERNET, (name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;maxSdkVersion=18)

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 31

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 23b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Android Activity
# use that parameter together with android.entrypoint to set custom Java class instead of PythonActivity
#android.activity_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest> element of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML code
#android.extra_manifest_xml = ./src/android/extra_manifest.xml

# (str) Extra xml to write directly inside the <manifest><application> tag of AndroidManifest.xml
# use that parameter to provide a filename from where to load your custom XML arguments:
#android.extra_manifest_application_arguments = ./src/android/extra_manifest_application_arguments.xml

# (str) Full name including package path of the Java class that implements Python Service
# use that parameter to set custom Java class which extends PythonService
#android.service_class_name = org.kivy.android.PythonService

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (bool) If True, your application will be listed as a home app (launcher app)
# android.home_app = False

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk assets directory.
# Either form may be used, and assets need not be in 'source.include_exts'.
# 1) android.add_assets = source_asset_relative_path
# 2) android.add_assets = source_asset_path:destination_asset_relative_path
#android.add_assets =

# (list) Put these files or directories in the apk res directory.
# The option may be used in three ways, the value may contain one or zero ':'
# Some examples:
# 1) A file to add to resources, legal resource names contain ['a-z','0-9','_']
# android.add_resources = my_icons/all-inclusive.png:drawable/all_inclusive.png
# 2) A directory, here  'legal_icons' must contain resources of one kind
# android.add_resources = legal_icons:drawable
# 3) A directory, here 'legal_resources' must contain one or more directories, 
# each of a resource kind:  drawable, xml, etc...
# android.add_resources = legal_resources
#android.add_resources =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = True

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_packaging_options =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Copy these files to src/main/res/xml/ (used for example with intent-filters)
#android.res_xml = PATH_TO_FILE,

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (str) screenOrientation to set for the main activity.
# Valid values can be found at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element
#android.manifest.orientation = fullSensor

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Android logcat only display log for activity's pid
#android.logcat_pid_only = False

# (str) Android additional adb arguments
#android.adb_args = -H host.docker.internal

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) XML file for custom backup rules (see official auto backup documentation)
# android.backup_rules =

# (str) If you need to insert variables into your AndroidManifest.xml file,
# you can do so with the manifestPlaceholders property.
# This property takes a map of key-value pairs. (via a string)
# Usage example : android.manifest_placeholders = [myCustomUrl:\"org.kivy.customurl\"]
# android.manifest_placeholders = [:]

# (bool) Skip byte compile for .py files
# android.no-byte-compile-python = False

# (str) The format used to package the app for release mode (aab or apk or aar).
# android.release_artifact = aab

# (str) The format used to package the app for debug mode (apk or aar).
# android.debug_artifact = apk

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android URL to use for checkout
#p4a.url =

# (str) python-for-android fork to use in case if p4a.url is not specified, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android specific commit to use, defaults to HEAD, must be within p4a.branch
#p4a.commit = HEAD

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false

# (str) extra command line arguments to pass when invoking pythonforandroid.toolchain
#p4a.extra_args =



#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.12.2

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) The development team to use for signing the debug version
#ios.codesign.development_team.debug = <hexstring>

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

# (str) The development team to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.development_team.release = <hexstring>

# (str) URL pointing to .ipa file to be installed
# This option should be defined along with `display_image_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.app_url =

# (str) URL pointing to an icon (57x57px) to be displayed during download
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `full_size_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.display_image_url =

# (str) URL pointing to a large icon (512x512px) to be used by iTunes
# This option should be defined along with `app_url` and `display_image_url` options.
#ios.manifest.full_size_image_url =


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .aab, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Although i haven't tried any thing i am expecting a red background with company logo at the center

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the pre splash it was due to custom-font which while packaging were not included or something so the simple solution i found was to just remove

> font_name: "Assets/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"

from every widget.